# Visual Studio 2015: Expected behavior when webtest with data source called by other webtests in load test scenario

Tags: visual-studio-2015, performance-testing

I have 3 webtests included in a loadtest scenario (at varying percentages of the test mix). Each of the 3 tests in my scenario call another webtest to accomplish the login portion of the flow. The login webtest being called is the same for all 3 main tests.

The login webtest contains a data source. It's a csv and the data access method is sequential. I am running my load test on a single AWS agent.

When I run a load test, I was expecting for the agent to get a single copy of the data file and use that single copy for all 3 of the webtests in the load test scenario. However, I see 2 tests using the same data row with only a 2 minute separation and other errors seem to suggest that the same data row is being used by 2 tests at one time. I am not running a high v-user load and think times are built into the test, so there's no way the load test could loop through the entire data file in 2 minutes.

I know the data source behavior is different when multiple agents are involved, but any insight on how the data source is managed when it's included in a test that's called by multiple other tests?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from my experiments each top-level test, ie each test named in the load test, gets its own copy of the data sources of called tests. Hence even though the data source is attached to the called (ie login) test each calling test will use all of its values.

**My experiment:** A very simple web test named `Called` has a CSV data source having 100 rows and a column containing the row number. This web test just visits `http://localhost/` and expects a 404 response. A `WebTestPlugin` has a `PostWebTest` method that writes the data source's row number field plus the context parameters `$WebTestIteration` and `WebTestUserId` to a log file. A second test has as its only actions (1) a call of `Called` and (2) a call of the plugin. Made copies of this second test and gave them the names `Caller1`, `Caller2` and `Caller3`. These three tests are used in a load test for 6 virtual users for 2 minutes duration. The log file clearly shows that each CSV row is used by each of the three top-level tests.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @AdrianHHH. Much appreciated!